# how to get values from drop down list in php

Tags: php

I have several drop down lists in a table, I am trying to retrive the value of the drop down list if its not 0.

I have a table of items each item has the drop down list. Below is how I create the drop down list, I give it the tableid as a name because this is a unique identifier for the particular product.

```
echo "<td><select name=". $row['goosedown_id'] .">
                <option value=''> 0 </option>
                <option>1</option>
                <option>2</option>
                <option>3</option>
                <option>4</option>
                <option>5</option>
                <option>6</option>
                <option>7</option>
                <option>8</option>
            </select>
        </td>";
```

Then once the form is submitted I am trying to just print any values i can... cause im not sure how to proceed... I do this like so.

```
$goosedown_id = check_input($_POST['goosedown_id']);
//..

goose down = $goosedown_id
```

I am hoping to be able to print out the associated values or calculate the price based off other items in the table i.e. price etc. but I am hoping someone can help me with trying to access the items that are no 0 first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the following example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <link href="loginmodule.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <?php
    if (count($_POST)) {
        for ($i = 0; $i < $_POST["nr_rows"]; $i++) {
            echo "<h2>id=".$_POST["goosedown_id"][$i].", qty=".$_POST["qty"][$i]."</h2>\n";
        }
        die("<pre>".print_r($_POST, true)."</pre>\n");
    } else {
        // connect to the database
        $link = mysqli_init();

        // Adjust hostname, username, password and database name before use!
        $db = mysqli_real_connect($link, "localhost", "root", "", "test") or die(mysqli_connect_error());

        $SQL = "SELECT * FROM 5050goosedown ORDER BY price ASC";
        $result = mysqli_query($link, $SQL) or die(mysqli_error($link));

        $rows = array();
        for ($i = 1; $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result); $i++){
            $rows[] = array(
                'id'        => $row['goosedown_id'],
                'bgcolor'   => ($i % 2) ? '#F5F5F5' : '#E5E5E5',
                'name'      => htmlentities($row['name']),
                'size'      => ($row['width'] || $row['height']) ? $row['width'].'/'.$row['height'] : '',
                'fill'      => $row['normal_fill'].'/'.$row['our_fill'],
                'old_price' => $row['old_price'] ? $row['old_price'] : '',
                'price'     => $row['price']
            );
        }
    }
    ?>
    <form action="<?= $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] ?>" method="post">
        <table border="0" width="600">
            <tr>
                <th width="30%" colspan="2"><b>50/50 Goose Down:</b></th>
                <th width="30%"><i>Normal Fill / Our Fill</i></th>
                <th width="12.5%"><i>Old Price</i></th>
                <th width="12.5%"><i>Price</i></th>
                <th width="12.5%"><i>Quantity</i></th>
            </tr>
            <?php foreach ($rows as $row): ?>
            <tr bgcolor="<?= $row['bgcolor'] ?>">
                <td><?= $row['name'] ?></td>
                <td><?= $row['size'] ?></td>
                <td><?= $row['fill'] ?></td>
                <td><?= $row['old_price'] ?></td>
                <td><?= $row['price'] ?></td>
                <td>
                    <select name="qty[]">
                        <?php for ($i = 0; $i <= 8; $i++): ?>
                        <option value="<?= $i ?>"><?= $i ?></option>
                        <?php endfor ?>
                    </select>
                    <input type="hidden" name="goosedown_id[]" value="<?= $row['id'] ?>" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <?php endforeach ?>
        </table>
        <input type="submit" name="myButton" id="myButton" value="Submit" />
        <input type="hidden" name="nr_rows" value="<?= count($rows) ?>">
    </form>    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you look at the source of the page you're building? Your form is going to be

```
<td><select name="value_of_the_variable_your_insert">
```

not

```
<td><select name="goosedown_id">
```

since you're inserting `$row['goosedown_id']`, you need to look for the VALUE of that variable, e.g.

```
$_POST[$row['goosedown_id']]
```

Comment: Could you fix your answer?  I don't see any extra right-square-bracket in his code.

Comment: oh okay.. it just kinda clicked.. after I read your post like 10 times.. so I put the $_POST[$row['goosedown_id']] in my reciving php file.

Comment: I am going to keep trying but I have not been able to get this to work yet :( thanks for the help anyway. looking at the source code has given me some more insight.